# Custom Post Type parent/child relationship rewrite rules for permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, hierarchical

I have been working on this for quite awhile but I'm stuck at rewriting the permalinks for both the parent and the child.

So I created two custom post types: `magazines` and `magazine-pages` both MUST be hierarchical. Also `magazine-pages` is part of the `magazine` custom post type:

[image]

Here's my code for that:

```
// Magazines
    $args = array(
        'label' => 'Magazines',
        'labels' => array(
            //my-labels
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 25,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( "slug" => "magazines" ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail'),
        'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-book'
    );

    register_post_type('magazines', $args);

    // Magazine pages
    $args = array(
        'label' => 'Magazine pages',
        'labels' => array(
            //my-labels
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "magazines" ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor'),
        'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=magazines'
    );

    register_post_type('magazine-pages', $args);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

> /magazines/magazine-1/magazine-page-1

Where

> /magazine-1
>   Should be a post from CPT `magazine` (parent)

and

> /magazine-page-1
>   Should be a post from CPT `magazine-pages` (child)

I did add the following rewrite rules to make this work, but unfortunately it doesn't. Only the parent page works, the child pages returns a 404 error.

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^magazines/([^/]*)/?','index.php?magazines=$matches[1]','top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^magazines/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?magazine-pages=$matches[2]','top' ); 
});
```

Did I do something wrong in the rewrite rules?
All the help is welcome!

Comment: Why do you use two custom post types? I don't see the benefit of doing this. To achive this url structure, you should work with categories / taxonomies to get the desired structure. My opinion without knowing the details of why 2 cpt..

Comment: Well the main reason why I choose for this is because I also build in a functionality where I can change the order of 'magazine-pages' inside a 'magazine'. Not sure if thats possible with categories / taxonomies. Maybe there is an other way to make this work but I feel like I'm almost there with this piece op code. Or can't I make this permalink structure work with 2 Custom Post Types?

Comment: In my opinion this is pretty awkward and not straight forward. To change the order of the listing of your CPT, simply use menu_order.. This gives you the option of sorting all posts in the backend (with ajax), addded up with taxonomies it should be much less complicated than the thing you are trying to achive. Please watch this video on YT, it is an excellent tutorial of Custom Post Types and covers everything you need (Also the sorting etc..). https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCiHL2LRpepabKBq8s6Y-Abg/search?query=Custom+Post+Type

Comment: Thanks @user3135691, I will watch the video and try to fix it with taxonomies.